# How to animate onDraw images in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am currently writing a custom TableLayout that will contain a grid of bitmap images, is there a way for my to animate how the images are drawn on the layout. That is, has the images are drawn by the OnDraw method, it should be displayed on the layout with animation.

A code sample will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by reading the [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) and [Animation Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) developer docs.  There are animation examples in ApiDemos.  Once you try to get some code down, people will probably be more likely to help you out with it than write it for you.